# Issue in setting up the Android emulator with React native

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I am fairly new to React native and trying to set up Android environment with Visual studio. All the installation has been fairly successful, however, when I try to run the sample app on the android emulator executing the `npx react-native run-android` command it shows below error -

```
'C:\Users\Home' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:109)
```

However, when i execute `adb devices` on visual studio, it shows the list of emulator connected -

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

What could be the possible reason? Is this because my users name is Home PC? (Is this because there is a space in between) and it is not able to get the correct path?

Answer (score 42):

This is because your `java` version is updated to the latest version and gradle is not supported with the installed version. what you can do is update the gradle as well

1. So go to `gradle/wrapper` folder inside the `android` folder
2. Edit `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and replace `distributionUrl`
       with following value
       `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. 
(I have jdk version 14.0.1 and I had Gradle 6.0.1)

Comment: Cool! This saved my day. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Amila for the hint. Worked for me!

Comment: thanks, i spent 2days for this issue finaly you save my time

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue.The problem is with the JDK. From JDK 14 i downgraded to JDK 11(LTS) version. And it worked.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Install Java **8** version, which is available  [Java 8 download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

> Gradle is not keeping up with the Java Latest versions, so roll back
>   to previous versions