# react-native program is not installed on the emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new project with React Native in *Windows 10* but it does not run with the run-android command.

I will summarize what I did because I think all the programs are installed:

1. I install both npm and node.
2. Java installation.
3. React installation.
4. In the Environment system, these are set.

```sh
ANDROID_HOME ---> C:\Users\IHC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME--> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-۱۴.۰.۱
path--> C:\Users\IHC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Users\IHC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Users\IHC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
C:\Users\IHC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-۱۴.۰.۱\bin
```

The error is:

```
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
     .
.
.
.

        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
enter code here
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753248/issue-in-setting-up-the-android-emulator-with-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on the android version installed, for latest version refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android and retry.

Answer (score 0):

That is installed, well  I did the following

1. remove jdk-۱۴.۰.۱ and i install  jdk-8u261-windows-x64
2. first of all run Oracle VM VirtualBox next run Genymotion

and in powershell

3. npm start -- --reset-cache
4. npm install -g npm@4
5. react-native run-android